# Spotify Follow Count Num

Tags: wordpress, spotify

I added the Spotify Follow Button Embed Code for our wordpress website.
Question: Is there a way to hide the number for followers the user have, the one showing on right after the follow button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to hide the follower count. Simply append `show-count=0` in the `uri` attribute.

Read more in the documentation for the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-follow-button/).